# Inspecting the body of a lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a compiler. I'd like to inspect a lambda function that is passed in for compilation so that I can generate optimized code, like so:

```
f(fn):
  print(fn.body)   # how can I write this?
  if fn.body == 2*x:  # is this possible?
    return lambda x: x << 1 

f(lambda x : 2 * x)
```

I am aware of the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html) module but I didn't find a way to look into a lambda function. For instance I tried doing this:

```
def foo(p):
  print("code: %a" % getsource(p))

foo(lambda x: x + 1)
```

But it would print `foo(lambda x: x + 1)\n` rather than just `lambda x: x + 1`

Comment: A compiler that compiles what?

Comment: a compiler that takes in python code, and generate another implement in python or other languages.

Comment: I don't follow. A compiler generally takes a string/text file as input. Are you compiling an in-memory Python object?

Comment: `inspect` isn't really "looking into" the function at all.  It just retrieves the line number(s) and filename from the function object, then reads the specified line(s) from the specified file.  You might have better luck with the `ast` module for getting a usable representation of Python code.

Comment: @selcuk Yes I am compiling an in-memory python object dynamically on the fly.

Comment: @jasonharper ast doesn't quite work as it expects the input code to be in a string form not as a Callable afaik.

Comment: A Python function object is *already* compiled, to bytecode. It doesn't contain any form of source code.

Comment: If you want to operate on source code, you should *take* source code, not a function object.

Comment: Also, the kind of transformations you're trying to apply require more type information than you have. For example, replacing `2*x` with `x << 1` is invalid when `x` is a string. Also, if your output is still going to be ordinary Python as opposed to machine code, you might be surprised what "optimal" actually looks like. `2*x` is *faster* than `x << 1` for typical CPython ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/) package.

```
import uncompyle6
f = lambda x: x*2
uncompyle6.deparse_code2str(f.__code__)
```

it returns `str` code:

```
return x * 2
```

Comment: Does this have docs somewhere besides the github readme?

Comment: @JRR I didn't see any, but it have some docstrings.