# Print source of lambda without surrounding call

Tags: python, lambda, abstract-syntax-tree, python-ast

If I define a function

```py
def foo(function):
    import inspect
    return inspect.getsource(function)
```

and then call it, I get:

```py
In [11]: foo(lambda x: x[0] + x[1]*2)
Out[11]: 'foo(lambda x: x[0] + x[1]*2)\n'
```

Note how it printed the entire line, rather than just the lambda function.

Is there a way to get it to output just the lambda?

Desired output:

```py
In [11]: foo(lambda x: x[0] + x[1]*2)
lambda x: x[0] + x[1]*2'
```

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve using a regular expression?

EDIT:

Example of how `ast.parse(inspect.getsource(function))` may fail:

```py
ast.parse(foo(
    lambda x: x+1))
```

Comment: Can't you just .split() the string?

Comment: split based on? can't do open bracket, because the lambda might include open brackets. looking for a robust way to do this if possible

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66254841/inspecting-the-body-of-a-lambda-function and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498679/how-can-i-get-exactly-the-code-of-a-lambda-function-in-python

Comment: use `partition('(')` and `rpartition(')')`

Answer (score 0):

`inspect.getsource` will return a string that not only includes the source code of the object that is being inspected, but also the full call trace of the function that the object is being passed to. For example:

```
def foo(function):
   import inspect
   return inspect.getsource(function)

val = foo(lambda x: x[0] + x[1]*2)
```

Will result in the string `'val = foo(lambda x: x[0] + x[1]*2)\n'` stored under `val`.

To more accurately pull the source of `function` in the string returned from `inspect.getsource(function)`, you can use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module, returning for the function source code by anchoring a search on the `foo` object name:

```
def foo(function):
   import inspect, ast
   src = inspect.getsource(function) #store function's source, including the call trace
   return [ast.unparse(i.args[0]) for i in ast.walk(ast.parse(src)) #parse the src string 
           if isinstance(i, ast.Call) and i.func.id == 'foo'][0] #find a call AST node where the name of the object is 'foo'

print(foo(lambda x: x[0] + x[1]*2))
```

Output:

```
'lambda x: x[0] + x[1] * 2'
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately, `ast.parse(src)` may fail

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Can you clarify how it might fall in your use cases?

Comment: sure, I've amended the question with an example, thanks

Comment: @ignoring_gravity What is the error message/output that the code above is producing when run on that example?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Also note that `ast.parse(inspect.getsource(function))` has to be passed to `ast.walk` so as to search for the foo call itself, and cannot be used standalone in this case.